# How to remove respond_to block from scaffold_controller template

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, generator, scaffolding

## how to customize scaffold generator #[was following this link](http://zigzag.github.io/2010/01/18/customizing-your-scaffold-template-become-easier-in-rails3.html)

class IdeasController < ApplicationController
      before_action :set_idea, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

```
  # GET /ideas
  # GET /ideas.json
  def index
    @ideas = Idea.all
  end

  # GET /ideas/1
  # GET /ideas/1.json
  def show
  end

  # GET /ideas/new
  def new
    @idea = Idea.new
  end

  # GET /ideas/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /ideas
  # POST /ideas.json
  def create
    @idea = Idea.new(idea_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @idea.save
        format.html { redirect_to @idea, notice: 'Idea was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @idea }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @idea.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /ideas/1
  # PATCH/PUT /ideas/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @idea.update(idea_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @idea, notice: 'Idea was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { head :no_content }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'edit' }
        format.json { render json: @idea.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /ideas/1
  # DELETE /ideas/1.json
  def destroy
    @idea.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to ideas_url }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_idea
      @idea = Idea.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def idea_params
      params.require(:idea).permit(:name, :description, :picture)
    end
end
```

How to remove all the respond_to code ?

Answer (score 3):

Use `respond_with` to make your controllers cleaner. [This apidoc](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/MimeResponds/respond_with) and 
[this screencast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/224-controllers-in-rails-3) will answer all your related questions.

Your controller methods will be as clean as this:

```
def update
  @idea.update(idea_params)
  respond_with @idea, notice: 'Idea was successfully updated.'
end
```

To apply that to default scaffold controller template, just copy the template content from [github](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/railties/lib/rails/generators/rails/scaffold_controller/templates/controller.rb) and put it into `RAILS_ROOT/lib/templates/rails/scaffold_controller/controller.rb`. Then apply the `respond_with` approach there.

Comment: When I followed these instruction I had no respond_with in the update action (and other actions), rather the generator produced a redirect_to.

Answer (score 2):

Just do so like this.

For e.g.

```
respond_to do |format|
  if @idea.save
    format.html { redirect_to @idea, notice: 'Idea was successfully created.' }
    format.json { render action: 'show', status: :created, location: @idea }
  else
    format.html { render action: 'new' }
    format.json { render json: @idea.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
  end
end
```

can be replaced with

```
if @idea.save
  redirect_to @idea, notice: 'Idea was successfully created.'
else
  render 'new
end
```

Comment: But this is for one time . Next time I create " rails generate scaffold posts name:string , body:textarea.... " This respond_to block will appear again .

Comment: wow, dude, there are so many serious problems that people are trying to solve and you are wasting your time with this? is it so hard to just delete the piece of code that you don't need? this doesn't require a good knowledge of ruby ;)

Comment: then don't use scaffolds. You can do rails generate model Post rails generate controller posts.

Comment: What if i give my code to some one and later they want to improve it . should I keep telling them that your suppose to delete some lines to add your lines ?

Comment: I'm sorry what. If you don't want those lines don't use scaffolds. It is as simple as that. Just generate the models and controllers independently as I mentioned above.

Comment: @Sakshi Jain see my answer to your question. It contains info on how to modify the controller template.

Comment: Thank you , roody and Althaf . I could write the template :)